# Differences between objdump and xxd

Tags: linux, endianness, objdump, xxd

I am trying to find a call function in a binary file, so I tried this:

1. Compile my code (in C),
2. Use the command: `mips-mti-linux-gnu-objdump -d myapp.elf> objdump.txt`
3. My function in objdump.txt file: `9d003350: 42000828 myfunction 0x1`

Now, I want to identify this function in myapp.bin when reading this from memory. But, I get this: `28080042`.

I tried to use the command: `xxd -ps myapp.bin> xxd.txt`
Just can find: `28080042`.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) conflict. `objdump` and `xxd` are giving you the same bytes, they're just using different endianness.

```
Actual bytes in order:
    28 08 00 42
Big endian value:
    28 08 00 42
Little endian value:
    42 00 08 28
```

`xxd -p` will print out the individual bytes in the file in the order in which they exist.

`objdump` is disassembling it, it knows that the bytes belong in groups of 4, and it's interpreting them as little-endian.

`xxd` can print in little-endian order, using the `-e` flag (with a default grouping of 4 bytes, use the `-g` flag to change the number of bytes per group). However, this is incompatible with the `-p` flag, because the `-p` flag ignores any grouping.

`objdump` can be made to print in big-endian order, using the `-EB` flag, however, this will affect what instructions it reports.