# xxd vs od - little/big endian or something else going on

Tags: endianness, xxd, od, tac

I am looking at a compiled java file on Ubuntu 22.04.
On bash, when i say `xxd A.class`, i get a hexdump that begins with `cafe babe` - this is what i expect.
But if i say `od -x A.class`, i get `feca beba` - why?

As an additional puzzler, both if is say `tac A.class | xxd` (reversal by line) AND `tac -r -s 'x\|[^x] | xxd` (reversal by character) i get the cafe babe pattern, while both cases piped into `od -x` instead of `xxd`  give `feca beba` - Here the reversal by character should result in one result of `beba feca`, or at least `babe cafe`, should it not? Please enlighten me. The `fe` represents one byte, is it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both commands are using different endianess for integer representation. It has already been discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41229024/20161294

Comment: What i don't get is if this is about endianness, how does feca beba happen? Endianness-change: cafebabe -> bebafeca , but what i observe:  fecabeba

Comment: An important factor is the number of bytes per group (word), ie. `xxd -e -g 2 A.class` will be equivalent to `od -x A.class`